# How do I keep the UITabBar after pushing view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So, I have the following structure on my storyboard. The TabBar item 2 is like a "more" tab and I want to keep the bottom TabBar after pushing a new view controller (in this case, pushing the purple VC).

I've seen some questions here saying that I should embed the **item 2** in a navigation controller. OK that worked, the bottom bar continues to appear if I push the purple VC. The problem I have now is that the orange navigation bar doesn't disappear and the blue navigation bar don't appear. The orange navigation bar should appear until the green vc, after pushing the purple vc, the navigation bar should change. I want this because if I'm in the purple VC I want to go back to the green VC but if the orange navigation bar is appearing, the back button goes back to the gray vc.

The gif is demonstrating the current behavior.
Could anyone help?

[image: Storyboard]
[image: Current behavior]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Navigation Controller` the item 2 belongs to.

Now you can change the navigation bar color by using

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red  //choose the color of your liking
```

inside the `viewDidLoad` of the `ViewController`.

Comment: I need the go to tab bar controller because is a selection screen that goes to "the main view" which is the tab bar.

Comment: no, I don't wanna change the bar tint color. What I want is that when I push the purple VC from the green VC, the back button would appear and it should show back to the green VC. In the current behavior the back button, when I'm in the purple VC, goes back to the Grey VC

Comment: yes, removing the navigation controller works but when the purple controller is pushed, the bottom tab bar disappears.

Comment: I managed to do it adding the code on purple vc: on view did load: self.tabbarController.navigationcontroller.isNavigationBarHidden = true

and in the other vc I set it to false

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code like--

**1-Objective c-**

```
productDetail *obj=[[productDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"productDetail" bundle:nil];

obj.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:NO];
```

**2-Swift-**

```
var obj = productDetail(nibName: "productDetail", bundle: nil)
obj.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: false)
```

Comment: Didn't work. There is this option on Attribute Inspector too.